# Find if node is a child magnolia CMS

Tags: magnolia

I need to find out if a node in magnolia is a child and who is the parent. This is so that I can recreate the elements in reverse order. For example I need to find out that the first node 1 is child of quicklinks area node and the second node 1 is child of linklist area node.

```
--quicklinks  [mgnl:area] 
 *--1         [mgnl:component]
  *--linklist [mgnl:area]
    *--1      [mgnl:component]
     *--links [mgnl:area]
      *--0    [mgnl:component]
```

What method can I use for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `info.magnolia.jcr.util.NodeUtil`.

It brings a lot functionality that can be used including finding all children or fetching the parent of a given node.

Cheers,

Hope That helps,

Answer (score 2):

`NodeUtil` is indeed a good starting point, as @Ducaz035 mentions. But you'll need to write a model class for this. If you want to keep things strictly on the template level, have a look at `cmsfn` ([Magnolia Templating Functions](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS61/cmsfn#cmsfn-Children)) and the [Freemarker documentation](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html#ref_builtin_reverse). You can do neat things like this:

```
Content: ${content}<br />
Parent: ${content?parent}
Siblings (children of parent):<ul>
[#list cmsfn.children(content?parent) as child]<li>${child}</li>[/#list]
</ul>
Reversed siblings (children of parent):<ul>
[#list cmsfn.children(content?parent)?reverse as child]<li>${child}</li>[/#list]
</ul>
```

Comment: I need to write a class that will retrieve the JCR structure of a page (properties of the page,  page areas and children of areas with properties) and export it to a YAML file. This class has to be linked to an Action in the Page App in Magnolia CMS.
As @Ducaz035 suggested I will make use of NodeUtil. How do I configure the Action in the Page App to invoke the new class? I never wrote a module for Magnolia CMS.

Comment: That is a completely different question... This would probably not be the correct place to answer it. That being said... Google for "Magnolia Actionbar Definition" and "Magnolia App Decoration" to get started. If this does not get you on the right track, then create a new question for it so that it can be properly answered. Good luck!